# Extract text between two dots, lead by a number

Tags: python, regex

I have basically read the content of a PDF file. Now, I am trying to figure out the headers. The consistency is - each header is in the following pattern:
"1. My Header. And then the text follows..."

As an example:

```
x = '1. Some Header. and some more text 2. Another Header. And that is the end'
import re
re.findall((r'[0-9]\..*\.'),x)
```

Tried that, but it didn't work out.

What I was hoping:
Best case: ['1. Some Header', '2. Another Header']
worst case: ['Some Header', 'Another Header']

Comment: Oh, additionally... I can have a header with header greater than 9. So: x = '1. Some Header. and some more text 2. Another Header. And that is the end.... 12. Last Header. And the wrap up '

Comment: What happens if text under one header also contains "1. Some Header"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
x = '1. Some Header. and some more text 2. Another Header. And that is the end'
result = re.findall('\d+\.\s+[\w\s]+(?=[\.$])', x)
```

Output:

```
['1. Some Header', '2. Another Header']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\d+\.[^.]+\.
```

[image]

---

```
x = '1. Some Header. and some more text 2. Another Header. And that is the end'
import re
re.findall((r'\d+\.[^.]\.'),x)
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/aPh95S/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If the header should start at 1, you could use a capturing group:

```
(?<!\S)([1-9][0-9]*\.[^.]+)\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iIvWh2/1)

Else you could use

```
(?<!\S)(\d+\.[^.]+)\.
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert what is directly on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d+\.[^.]+` match 1+ digits, dot and 1+ times any char except a dot
- `)\.` Close group 1 and match a dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iIvWh2/2) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/OQ7Vq5)

For example using re.findall

```
import re 

regex = r"(?<!\S)(\d+\.[^.]+)\." 
test_str = "1. Some Header. and some more text 2. Another Header. And that is the end"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

Result

```
['1. Some Header', '2. Another Header']
```